# django - how can I join two models with ForeignKeys to the same users?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have multiple models like this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    model1_filed1 = models.CharField()


class Model2(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    model2_filed1 = models.CharField()

....
```

As you can see all the models have a filed `user = models.ForeignKey(User)` on each model so when I save my model data I know what user saved it.

On my project I need to:

1. Do a search on model1_filed1 (Moldel1). Something like find all the records from Model1 that have model1_filed1 containing the string "foo".
2. Once I find Model1 records containing the tring "foo"  on the mode1_filed1 join all the records from Model2 that have the same user id as the Model1 records just found.

Any ides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# 1
m1 = Model1.objects.filter(model1_filed1__contains='foo')

# 2
m2 = Model2.objects.filter(user__in=[x.user_id for x in m1])

# or one-liner for # 2, may be heavier for DB than two requests
m2 = Model2.objects.filter(user__model1__model1_filed1__contains='foo')
```

Comment: This would probably work is just I was hoping there was a way to do some kind a join so instead of two expressions m1 and m2 there will be just m1 that will do all the work.

Comment: Can this be done as well on Model1 and how? Right now all the "action" is on Model2 but because of some existing code I would prefer to do the join on Model1.

Comment: @avatar Just replace `model1` with `model2` and vice versa.